# rails pagination for custom queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following custom query:

`@initial_matches = Listing.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM listings WHERE industry = ? AND years <= ? AND degree_type <= ?", current_user.industry, current_user.years, @highest_degree])`

Any way to paginate the results?

Comment: Why do you use `find_by_sql`? Just don't use it and don't have any problems.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do the above statement otherwise...any suggestions on how to not use find_by_sql for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Listing.where(:industry => current_user.industry).where(["years <= ?", current_user.years]).where(["degree_type <= ?", @highest_degree]).paginate
```

Better move this logic to scopes for this to look prettier and shorter.

Answer (score 3):

[Will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) works fine with basic Arrays.

In your controller:

```
@stuffs = %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
```

In your view:

```
<% @stuffs.each do |stuff| %>
 <%= stuff %>
<% end  %>
<%= will_paginate @stuffs %>
```

Comment: +1. That's interesting. Thank you, I haven't thought about this.